# C# SonarQube complaining to Null pointers should not be dereferenced

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-analysis

I am facing issue in SonarQube, when i am trying to access value directly from model property it is showing error in sonar qube. please suggest.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check if `vehicleDetail` is `null` on line 5 in your method, which means that it could be null in some cases. SonarQube warns you that in those cases you will get `NullReferenceException` when you add the `AgentCode` to the command parameters.

If `vehicleDetail` is anticipated to be `null` indeed, the SonarQube issue is actually pointing to a bug in your code and you should wrap all member access of `vehicleDetail` in `if (vehicleDetail != null)`.

If `vehicleDetail` is not supposed to be null, you should remove the null check from the `if` statement in the beginning of the method and add a normal argument check that throws `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Yes true my issue has been resolved. but i have concern that line of code is also increasing.  Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee in your code that the parameter is not `null`. If it is, your program just crashes.

How you handle this is up to you. Check the parameter and throw an `ArgumentNullException` if it's null? Assume a default value if it's null? Not use any of it's properties if it's null? That's up to you to decide.

The message is telling you, that you *must* decide what to do in that case, not just hand-wave it and assume it will never happen.

Comment: Yes totally agree with your point, but for sonar qube issue do i need to add if condition for all ?

Comment: Sonarqube wants you to never run into a NullReferenceException. So I guess yes. You need to do that for all parts of your program.

Comment: Thank you a lot for help. Yes it is working when i am adding if condition but it is increasing line of one is there any alternative ?

Comment: Not really... you could probably ignore the rule in SonarQube, but it's a good rule so... it would kinda defeat the purpose of running SonarQube if you start ignoring rules.